# Where can I get a graph of lift coefficient against AOA for a symmetrical airfoil?

Tags: wing, airfoil, stability

Where can I get get a graph lift coefficient against AOA for a symmetrical airfoil ? I am asking for a source or link to a graph or table of AOA against Cl of any symmetrical airfoil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Search symmetrical airfoils in Airfoil Tools DB](http://airfoiltools.com/search/index?m%5BmaxCamber%5D=0&m%5Bsort%5D=5)

[Quabeck Sailplane 10 as an example](http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/details?airfoil=hq010-il)

[image]

[image]

Comment: What causes the wiggle in the middle for 2 of the curves?

Comment: @CrossRoads Low Reynold's number effects. I'll take those two out and leave the normal looking ones.

Comment: Amazing,thanks pilothead